# Can all superposition states be rebased into eigenstates?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, mathematics, superposition

In quantum mechanics, we can choose which basis in which to represent a system's state. A superposition state in one basis can be an eigenstate in another basis.

I was wondering if this is *always* true. I mean, if, for any given quantum system in any given state, there **must** exist some basis in which that state is an eigenstate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any (normalised) state $|\psi\rangle$ we can construct the operator $P_{|\psi\rangle} =|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$.

We then have
$$
P_{|\psi\rangle}|\psi\rangle = |\psi\rangle\langle\psi|\psi\rangle = |\psi\rangle
$$
so $|\psi\rangle$ is an eigenvector of $P_{|\psi\rangle}$ with eigenvalue $1$. Furthermore we have
$$
P_{|\psi\rangle}^\dagger = |\psi\rangle\langle\psi| = P_{|\psi\rangle}
$$
so $P_{|\psi\rangle}$ is Hermitian and so has a complete basis of eigenvectors. We therefore have a complete, orthogonal basis which includes $|\psi\rangle$.

Answer (score 0):

"A superposition state in one basis can be an eigenstate in another basis." I'm not sure I agree with this language. A state is either an eigenstate **of a specific operator $A$**, or it isn't. Whether that state can be written as a single basis state or not is, of course, basis dependent, but that is a separate question.

To answer that separate question, we can look to the [Gram-Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process). If your given state is $\psi$, you first check if it is proportional to any of your basis states $\{\phi_i \}$. If it is, you are done. If not, then you replace one of the $\phi_i$ with $\psi$, and then you perform the Gram-Schmidt process on your new set of states. This will make a new basis where $\psi$ is one of the basis states.

Answer (score 0):

> In quantum mechanics, we can choose which basis in which to represent a system's state. A superposition state in one basis can be an eigenstate in another basis.

That's true only for pure states, but it is not true that mixed states are eigenstates of some operator in another basis.  (In a way that's how mixed states are different from pure states: they are not eigenstates of an observable.)  For pure states it is certainly true that we can always do an change of basis in a finite dimensional spaces but the difficulty is that "another basis" might not have any particular physical contents.

Thus your statement is not strictly true if you allow mixed states, and is not necessarily true in infinite dimensional space.

The key point here is that bases in quantum mechanics *could* be just some random set of basis states but instead they are constructed to have a physical contents as they are eigenstates of a complete set of commuting observables.  At least we know that observables, which are self-adjoint, do have a complete set of eigenvectors, and the observables themselves have a physical meaning so the basis states can be used for projective measurements of the type $\vert \psi_\alpha\rangle\langle \psi_\alpha\vert$, where $\alpha$ denotes the an $n$-tuple of eigenvalues of the observables in the commuting set of $n$ observables.